# Setting a responsive background image to a div in HTML

Tags: html, css, image, background, responsive

How do I make this background image visible and responsive? (Note: I know I should use a CSS seperately, but the Content Management System I use won't let me add seperate CSS files..)

If is set up the code like this, the image is not displayed:

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-image:url('................');
    background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover;">
<div style="float:left; width: 32%; height:100%; display: inline-block;">
</div>
<div style="float:left; width: 32%; height:100%; display: inline-block;">
</div>
<div style="float:left; width: 32%; height:100%; display: inline-block;">
</div>
</div>
```

And like this, the image is displayed, but not responsive:

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-image:url('................');
    background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover; height:150px;">
<div style="float:left; width: 32%; height:100%; display: inline-block;">
</div>
<div style="float:left; width: 32%; height:100%; display: inline-block;">
</div>
<div style="float:left; width: 32%; height:100%; display: inline-block;">
</div>
</div>
```

Many thanks!

Comment: If you are using percentage heights make sure the parent height is defined.

Comment: ...and clear the floats.

Answer (score 0):

how about using background-size as contain? in this jsfiddle it works
https://jsfiddle.net/8fyLbj6r/

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-image:url('http://images.firstcovers.com/covers/i/its_easy_if_you_try-5332.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:contain; height:150px;">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I need to rescale the image now, but at least it's visible. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

**Do->** Add float:left to your first div with background image.
**Reason->** height in % is relative,in your code their is no relativity with any other div.something like 100% of 0 = 0.

P.S incase you want your 1st div to be placed above and not at background then put in img tag in empty div.but then again height would be needed to be mentioned in px.Try 1st approach.